# Как вводить переменные в django?

Tags: django

Вот есть у меня модель. Текст. Его можно вводить через админ панель, но как отобразить ввод на сайте, так чтобы пользователь мог ввести значение этой самой модели? Как-то через input в html?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте формы. Создайте в каталоге вашего приложения файл `forms.py`. В этом файле создайте форму с нужным типом поля (`forms.Textarea`). Эту форму импортируйте в файле `views.py` и передайте её в ваш шаблон.html.
Тут простой пример: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_forms/

Comment: Спасибо большое! :-*